# Use MailCore to send Email with yahoo account in my own app

Tags: iphone, ios, smtp, yahoo, mailcore

I succeeded in sending email with google account but failed with yahoo account in my app. MailCore is used to compose my email data.

```
#define YAHOO_SEND_SERVER_1       @"smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
#define YAHOO_SEND_PORT         465

success = [CTSMTPConnection sendMessage:testMsg server:YAHOO_SEND_SERVER_1 username:account password:pwd port:YAHOO_SEND_PORT useTLS:YES useAuth:YES error:&error];
```

I got the error description:

```
error: Error Domain=mailcore Code=1 "Unexpected error code" UserInfo=0xc9b9740 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected error code}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

MailCore should have been updated to support Yahoo SMTP, you need to use:

```
- (BOOL) sendMessage:server:username:password:port:connectionType:useAuth:error
```

For `connectionType:` use **`CTSMTPConnectionTypeStartTLS`**.